# How to autoplay Vimeo video with mute=0?

Tags: video, iframe, vimeo, autoplay

I am trying to autoplay a Vimeo video. this video is an intro video on my website. Video autoplay is working fine with mute=1 but I want mute=0 and the autoplay not working because of policy changed.
How can I autoplay video with sound on?

This is my iframe:
`<iframe id="quboyvideo" class="iframeVideo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/442568283?autoplay=1&mute=0" width="640" height="355" frameborder="0" style="font-size:0px;" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" id="introVideo"></iframe>`

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. Autoplaying videos with sound isn't possible with most modern browsers (not to mention most viewers find this to be an undesired user experience), so even if the Vimeo Player were to allow the usecase it may be blocked on the browser level. Take a look at the Vimeo Help Center here, specifically the "Autoplay Restrictions" section: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-and-looping-embedded-videos
2. If you do want to mute a video by specifying the parameter in the embed code, the correct name is `muted` not `mute`. Embed parameters are documented here:

https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001494447-Using-Player-Parameters
https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/embed